# passing array and checking the values

Tags: php, mysql

While creating a group with user ids, I am checking if the entered id exists in database. If it exists, group should be created, if not it should pop out an error.

I am passing array with user ids to a function `user_check`, but it is not getting checked. Here is my code:

```
<?php

    function user_check($user_id)
    {
        $u1 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT uid from users where uid<>'" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'");
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($u1)) {
            $users = $row['uid'];
            echo "users" . $users;
            $users1 = sort($users);
            $users2 = sort($user_id);
            printf($users1);
            if ($user1 == $user2) {
                echo "same";
            } else {
                echo "not same";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You pass a user_id to your function, then you reference $_SESSION['user_id'], is that what you wanted?

Comment: Is this your first programm on php?

Comment: Your code doesn't have an ending `}`

Comment: `sort` does not return an array.

Comment: You need to add examples of the different variables, the code suggests that `$_POST['users']` is an array but you also treat `$row['uid']` as if it is an array. Which it is not.

Comment: Your parameter is called `$user_id` (which suggests a single ID), but you are passing an `array()`. `$users` will not be available in your function, take a look at [Variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: Where are `$user1` and `$user2` assigned?

Comment: Please, don't trust your user input. Validate and sanitize *all* user input *always*.

Comment: There is too much wrong here, you should probably start over. It seems you want to check each sent-in id against the database or get the whole bunch using `IN` and check if the number of rows matches the number of array elements.

Comment: No `$con` defined.

Answer (score 0):

Given a list of user_ids (that you have validated/filtered already) you could write a function something like the following (untested):

```
function all_users_exist(array $user_ids, Mysqli $con)
{
    $result_uids = [];
    $ids         = implode(',', $user_ids);
    $sql         = "SELECT uid from users WHERE uid IN ($ids)";
    $result      = $con->query($sql);
    if($result)
        while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
            $result_uids[] = $row['uid'];
    sort($user_ids);
    sort($result_uids);

    return $user_ids == $result_uids;
}
```